# Book for understanding synthetic techniques and apparatus(with pictures)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reference-request, books

Is there a standard textbook to understand numerous laboratory apparatus and the assembly techniques that can be used for carrying out different processes (with pictures)?

I have been cleaning my lab and came across many glassware, from as long as 30 years back which I don't have much idea about regarding their usage. Is there a book which could help me in understanding and classifying the resources that i have with me?

P.S. I am in a crystal engineering lab.

Comment: The *best* is rather subjective I'm afraid. Here at SE (sorry I forgot to welcome you, anyway, welcome), we deal with questions that can be answered with facts, and that have a definite answer. However, your question demands opinions, rather than facts, so we can't give you a precise and definite answer. Voting to close this question as Primarily opinion based. Since you're looking for resources (something asked commonly), we have a list of books. Do check it out: [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)

Comment: And I am sorry , though I know I should not be asking questions with multiple answers or subjective interpretations , but I had exhausted all my resources of getting good advice on this question. Sorry again. Cheers mates and thanks for help, please proceed as per policies. Thank you

Comment: Come to think of it, we don't have a section for practical/experimental chemistry within the [Resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/16683) post. This would be a decent addition, since there are, of course, plenty of books on the topic.

Comment: I agree. This should have been closed **if and only if** there already is a pertinent subsection on the topic of resources. The OP knows that book opinions will differ. The word 'best' is hence not an issue (in my opinion); it could have been edited without changing the meaning of the question.